# Android 11 - Creating app-specific directory on external storage

Tags: android, scoped-storage

Recently, I'm trying to migrate my application from SDK-29 to SDK-30.
And one thing I concerned the most is scoped storage.

I saw on [official document](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific#external-access-files) that says "On Android 11 (API level 30) and higher, apps cannot create their own app-specific directory on external storage."

So I tried it out to create my own directory inside external storage and write a new file to it. The code looks like this :

```kotlin
// creating new directory under external storage
val appDir = File(applicationContext.getExternalFilesDir(null), "play")
appDir.mkdir()

// writing new file under my own directory
val newFile = File(appDir.absolutePath, "test.jpg")
val outputStream = FileOutputStream(newFile)
val inputStream = resources.openRawResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
val data = byteArrayOf()
inputStream.read(data)
outputStream.write(data)
inputStream.close()
outputStream.close()
```

I expected this code will crash but it works. I find the file at the given path. So, I'm a little confused the meaning of that note.

What do Google means with "cannot create their own app-specific directory on external storage"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are referring to creating arbitrary directories off of the external storage root (e.g., `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`.

`getExternalFilesDir()` and similar methods on `Context` are fine solutions to use instead!

Comment: @t0m: Yes! For cases where the user will want the files to stick around after an uninstall... for recognized media formats, use `MediaStore`, otherwise use `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` and the Storage Access Framework. See [this lengthy blog post series](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/19/scoped-storage-stories-saf-basics.html) for notes about those options.

Comment: I am totally confused from `MediaStore` and Storage Access Framework. All Android tutorials use File API, I have app where I am working with File API on 100+ places and now I will have to refactoring all code to work with MediaStore, SAF and Uris? :-| There is no solution for this case: user selects/creates directory on SDcard root for example the same like ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE for example and system grants r/w permissions and returns File path for later use with File API.

Answer (score 1):

To create app-specific directory on external storage but off root.

```
private fun createDir(directoryName: String): File? {
        val file = File(applicationContext.getExternalFilesDir("/"),directoryName)
        if (!file?.mkdirs())
            print("Volume : " + "Directory not created")

        return file
    }
```

**Note: For that does not required any storage permission.**

To create app-specific directory on external storage in root.

> **Note: This is only work for Android 11.**

Request for All files access from the user:

1. Declare the **MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** permission in the manifest.
2. Use the **ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION** intent action to
   direct users to a system settings page where they can enable the
   following option for your app: Allow access to manage all files.
3. To determine whether your app has been granted the
   **MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** permission, call
   **Environment.isExternalStorageManager()**.

> Write code on OnCreate Method:

```
if (!isExternalStorageReadable()) return

if (!Environment.isExternalStorageManager()) {
            val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION)
            intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT")
            intent.data = Uri.parse(String.format("package:%s", applicationContext.packageName))
            startActivityForResult(intent, 20)
        } else {
            createDir("ddddd")
        }
```

> Declare two functions outside from OnCreate:

```
private fun isExternalStorageReadable(): Boolean {
        return Environment.getExternalStorageState() in
                setOf(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED, Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY)
    }

private fun createDir(directoryName: String): File? {
        val file = File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("/"),directoryName)
        if (!file?.mkdirs())
            print("Volume : " + "Directory not created")

        return file
    }
```

Comment: Work for all versions. Plz check the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68032841/folder-listfiles-is-returning-null-in-android-11/70527486#70527486

Answer (score 0):

do you know if can we officially crete own folder in /storage/sdcard0/Android/data/package/files in the following way:

val myTestFolder = File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "testFolder")
myTestFolder.mkdirs()

?

I'm doing in this way since the android 11 was released, but in this days I have some permission issue on Samsung Tab S7 and S8.