# why directory.listFiles() is returning null in place of file array in android 11

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-studio

Please tell me how to read all files from a specific directory like if we want to make status saver app so we would have to read all files from /storage/whatsapp/Media/.statuses/ using folder.listFiles()
till android it was working fine bt now
it is returning null
I have taken runtime permissions
I have added MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in manifest
but still it is not working
you can see my code from

[folder.listfiles() is returning null in android 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68032841/folder-listfiles-is-returning-null-in-android-11)

Nd please do it in java

Comment: Do you know the difference between returning a null pointer and returning an empty list? You did not react there. And with this new post you did not clear up anything.

Comment: `/storage/whatsapp/Media/.statuses/ ` That is an impossible path to begin with. A null can be expected.

Comment: sorry typing mistake
path is /storage/emulated/0/whatsapp/Media/.statuses