# How to make a hidded folder in Above Android 11

Tags: android, kotlin, directory

I try to create a hidden folder in an external public directory using the code that follows

```
"${Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM}/.folderName/"
```

The folder was created but the folder name was _.foldername that folder is visible in the external directory. how do I create a hidden folder in Android 12 anyone please help me?

Comment: Your 'code' does not create a folder to begin with. It does nothing.

Comment: @blackapps No issue for folder creation. But the issue was folder name was created (_.folderName) expected result was (.folderName). Do you have any idea regarding hidden folder creation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make without Permission.

1. you need permission from the user
2. user will choose allow then only you can otherwise you can't
3. in case of scope storage you will have limited permission for public directory only like downloads, music, etc

you can refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70602644/8084692)

Comment: Thank you. I added permission as you mentioned above.

Comment: @ShobanaVelmurugan if it's helpful to you then please mark it as right answer :)

Comment: I didn't get the expected answer from your side, so I have not mentioned the correct answer.

Comment: @ShobanaVelmurugan answer never expected one. you need permission first as I defined in the first step.

Comment: marked as a correct answer