# get files and send telegram bot android

Tags: java

I tried to make a program that will receive files from the directory "/storage..." and send a telegram to the bot. But I get a crash. Help

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button sendButton;
    private final String BOT_TOKEN = "5949193548:AAE9KL2W4SsydxrDYGbxozUIM4UAHDaHfpg";
    private final String ADMIN_CHAT_ID = "1045144875";
    private final String IMAGE_DIRECTORY = "/storage/emulated/0/files/";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        sendButton = findViewById(R.id.send_files);
        sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //sendMessageToBot();
                //  sendMessageToAdmin();
                sendImages();
            }
        });
    }

     private void sendImages() {
        File directory = new File(IMAGE_DIRECTORY);
        File[] files = directory.listFiles();
        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.isFile() && file.getName().endsWith(".jpg")) {
                new SendMessageTask().execute("https://api.telegram.org/bot" + BOT_TOKEN + "/sendMessage?chat_id=" + ADMIN_CHAT_ID + "&photo=hello");
            }
        }
    }
 
    
        private class SendMessageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
                    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    connection.setDoOutput(true);
                    connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
                    connection.setReadTimeout(5000);
                    connection.connect();
                    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                    String content = "", line;
                    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                        content += line + "\n";
                    }
                    return content;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return null;
                }
            }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            if (result != null) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Image sent!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error sending image!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to make a program that will receive files from the directory "/storage..." and send a telegram to the bot. But I get a crash.

Comment: You should immediately renew your bot token, if that is indeed your real token. Never share those secrets with anyone!
Also, could you please provide the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: I changed the token, don't worry. Unfortunately I can't

Comment: Are you running the app on a physical device or on emulator? In case you're using Android Studio, it should display errors in the console.

Comment: yes in android studio. In any case, the code is not quite working

Comment: `directory.listFiles()` seems to return `null`, which leads to a crash. This seems to occur due to the app missing permissions to access the storage, please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68032841/file-listfiles-is-returning-null-in-android-11

Comment: new SendMessageTask().execute("https://api.telegram.org/bot" + BOT_TOKEN + "/sendMessage?chat_id=" + ADMIN_CHAT_ID + "&photo=hello");
I just now noticed that my photo is being sent incorrectly, the method specified is a message and I need a Photo

here is an example of a computer version written in Python. How to implement it correctly in the android version?

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    file_path = os.path.join(directory, filename)
    if os.path.isfile(file_path):
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
            bot.send_document(admin_chat_id, f)

Comment: You seem to be using a library for the telegram api in python. You're not using one in java so you have to manually craft a http request that sends the file, which is fairly complicated if you're not familiar with it. I'd recommend you to use a java library for the telegram api like you did with python.

Comment: could you provide the code ?

Comment: No, I'm not familiar with the telegram api. To get started, find a java library for the telegram api (google it) and add it to the module's `build.gradle` file in your android studio project. Then read the library's docs to see how to use it and upload files.

Comment: my manifest file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: You need to add the library to the module's `build.gradle`, not the manifest. It's also documented on the official android studio docs: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies

Comment: I chose 'org.telegram:telegrambots:4.9.1'
some said I had a problem in the storage access permission so I showed

Comment: Yes, you should read the top answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/70527486/11141917 and see if it works for you.

Comment: after using it, I get duplicate class errors

Comment: Could you provide the error message?

Comment: After a little thought, I decided to do it through php. And that was the best solution.

Comment: could you help where to specify the path to the directory "/storage..."
  Cursor query = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external"), new String[]{"_data"}, null, null, String.valueOf("_size") + " DESC");